# Tamaño de archivo compilado a .exe con pyinstaller

Tags: python, compilar, compilador

quiero compilar mi archivo.py a .exe mediante la aplicación pyinstaller, mi script básicamente se conecta a equipos vía telnet/ssh guardo log,analizo con pandas y devuelve un excel.
La consulta  es si hay posibilidad de disminuir el tamaño del .exe compilado generado (95MB), ocupo las siguientes librerías:

```
import time
import telnetlib
from flatten_json import flatten
import pandas as pd
import paramiko
import datetime
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler, utils
```

es posible reducir el tamaño del archivo compilado  importando  'SOLO' las librarías que realmente utiliza el script? y no todo el modulo? por ejemplo paramiko? como puedo saber que estoy utilizando de este modulo? e importar solo la librería que se utiliza del modulo? sería algo como from flatten_json import flatten  ?  mi razonamiento es correcto  o estoy diciendo cualquier cosa??

espero puedan guiarme a entender como podría  reducir el tamaño del script compilado a .exe

desde ya gracias, saludos...

Comment: Es correcto, si estas utilizando `paramiko` y quieres saber que utilizas de ese módulo, lo más probable es que en alguna parte estés haciendo esto `paramiko.algo` ese algo es lo que estás utilizando

Comment: hola @Christian gracias por tu respuesta, no me queda claro el tema aun, o sea, si tengo el comando ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()  entonces debería importar solo la librería, from paramiko import SSHClient()  otro ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) seria  from paramiko import AutoAddPolicy()  ?  así iría agregando las librería que uso de los módulos? y ocuparía menos espacio el complicado? gracias

Comment: si, pero sin los paréntesis `from parmiko import  SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy`, y creo que así se reducirá el tamaño (no he trabajado con pyintaller)

Comment: realice el from import de las librerías ... pero sigue compilando con el mismo tamaño, es por otro lado e tema de tamaño pareciera, gracias de todos modos...  sabrás de otro compilador  a .exe para probar, gracias saludos

Comment: lastimosamente nop, tal vez @DanteS. te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Pude reducir el tamaño del script de 95MB a 19MB siguiendo los pasos del siguiente link: https://jdhao.github.io/2019/10/14/python_script_to_exe/      saludos y gracias @Christian

Comment: de nada, pero es mejor hacer una respuesta incluyendo algunos ejemplos